# ERROR 404 after submitting a form with POST request

Tags: python, django, django-forms

http://127.0.0.1:8000/tasks works fine but when when I add a task and submit it, I get a 404 thrown at me,

ERROR: Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

```
admin/
polls/
newyear/
tasks/ [name='index']
tasks/ add [name='add']
The current path, tasks/{ % url 'add' % }, didn't match any 
of these
```

mysite\tasks\urls.py

```
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
path("", views.index, name='index'),
path("add", views.add, name='add')]
```

mysite\mysite\urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('polls/',include('polls.urls')),
path('newyear/', include('newyear.urls')),
path('tasks/', include('tasks.urls'))]
```

mysite\tasks\views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
tasks = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
def index(request):
   return render(request, "tasks/index.html", { 
    "tasks": tasks
 })
  def add(request):
     return render(request, "tasks/add.html")
 
  )
```

mysite\tasks\templates\tasks\index.html

```
   {% extends "tasks/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
<h1>
    Tasks
</h1>
   <ul>
    {%for task in tasks%}
        <li> {{task}}</li> 
    {%endfor%}

    </ul>
    <a href="{% url 'add' %}">Add a New Task</a>
  {% endblock %}
```

mysite\tasks\templates\tasks\add.html

```
{% extends "tasks/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
<h1>
    Add Task
</h1>
<form action= "{ % url 'add' % }" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="task">
    <input type="submit">

</form>  
<a href= "{% url 'index' %}">View Tasks</a>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: coz you didnt write code of post request.

Comment: path("add/", views.add, name='add')] does trailing slash help?

Comment: @SuryaPratapRana Kindly elaborate?

Comment: @AlexeyPopov nope

Comment: @KwakuE.Biney tasks/{ % url 'add' % } is it the exact request.path? It looks like your 'add' name is not being reversed

Comment: @AlexeyPopov Unfortunately, I don't understand your question

Comment: @KwakuE.Biney "{ % url 'add' % }" remove spaces between braces and percent signs

Comment: @AlexeyPopov THANK YOU!! this did the trick! didn’t think it would make such a difference!

Comment: @KwakuE.Biney you're welcome

Answer (score 0):

Aside from Alexey Popov's answer to fix broken tags with space `{% ... %}`, also remember to add within your form a csrf token:

```
<form action= "{% url 'add' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    ...
```